# How to navigate to folders with spaces in

Tags: macos, terminal

How to create alias to a folder, and how to go to the alias folder -> from TERMINAL (not by "open folder_name-alias")

[image]

We Have to operate everything on terminal (go to the directory of alias)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create an alias for go to your folder you can open **~/.bash_profile** file and enter the row like this:

```
alias goToMyDir='cd path/to/your/directory'
```

And use

```
$ goToMyDir
```

Also you can create symbolic link for it:

```
$ ln -s path/to/your/directory yourDir
```

And after you can just use

```
$ cd yourDir
```

P.S.
If you will make an alias, you should restart your Terminal session.

Comment: I think you are maybe confusing the issue here. The OP is talking about a macOS *"Finder alias"*, and you have started off talking about a *"bash alias"*, then moved on to *"symbolic links"* and finally ended up where you started, talking about *"bash aliases"*.